# Is there a short data type in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to read from a binary data file in R. According to the file format, I must at first read 2 bytes header data which represents the size of the payload and after that, I must read n bytes. So, I need to read a 2 byte(short) from the binary file but in R, I could not find 2-bytes short data type.
Does a short type really not exist in R? If so, how can I read 2 bytes and interpret this 2 byte as a short value?

Comment: would the `size` parameter of the `readBin` function help?

Comment: @Waldi thanks it solved. i've read the documentation but I don't how I missed that point.